# Duplicate row in R with condition is met

Tags: r

I'm trying desperately to fix an issue with my data, but I can't seem to find anything in the forums that will help (or I know so little that I'm not searching for the correct thing).

I have the following data, and when the value in the Mumbai Column is equal to zero, I would like to duplicate that entire row and copy it underneath.

Is there any way to do this in R, or am I better off calling a VBA script?

Before:

```
Row Shanghai    Mumbai  Beijing Paris   Hong Kong   Wellington
5.7 0.4 6.2 9.9 4.1 3.4
5.1 7.5 1.8 9.2 4.8 9.9
5.0 1.5 4.4 7.2 4.5 6.6
5.7 5.4 6.7 9.1 2.9 9.0
8.2 7.7 2.3 9.8 0.2 3.1
3.4 0.0 6.5 5.4 0.2 0.5
1.0 9.5 2.8 5.7 2.8 2.5
8.4 9.9 2.1 6.3 9.3 8.4
3.8 3.4 5.1 5.8 0.7 1.8
4.5 3.9 8.3 5.8 7.3 4.7
5.3 8.9 9.2 9.7 2.8 0.2
0.7 0.0 2.3 4.6 5.9 2.8
1.4 2.6 4.0 7.2 5.5 1.0
4.7 8.2 4.1 5.0 8.9 3.0
8.9 4.7 0.2 4.0 1.0 7.8
```

After

```
Shanghai    Mumbai  Beijing Paris   Hong Kong   Wellington      
5.7 0.4 6.2 9.9 4.1 3.4     
5.1 7.5 1.8 9.2 4.8 9.9     
5.0 1.5 4.4 7.2 4.5 6.6     
5.7 5.4 6.7 9.1 2.9 9.0     
8.2 7.7 2.3 9.8 0.2 3.1     
3.4 0.0 6.5 5.4 0.2 0.5     
3.4 0.0 6.5 5.4 0.2 0.5     # DUPLICATE ROW
1.0 9.5 2.8 5.7 2.8 2.5     
8.4 9.9 2.1 6.3 9.3 8.4     
3.8 3.4 5.1 5.8 0.7 1.8     
4.5 3.9 8.3 5.8 7.3 4.7     
5.3 8.9 9.2 9.7 2.8 0.2     
0.7 0.0 2.3 4.6 5.9 2.8     
0.7 0.0 2.3 4.6 5.9 2.8     # DUPLICATE ROW
1.4 2.6 4.0 7.2 5.5 1.0     
4.7 8.2 4.1 5.0 8.9 3.0     
8.9 4.7 0.2 4.0 1.0 7.8
```

Input data:

```
structure(list(Shanghai = c(5.7, 5.1, 5, 5.7, 8.2, 3.4, 1, 8.4,             
3.8, 4.5, 5.3, 0.7, 1.4, 4.7, 8.9), Mumbai = c(0.4, 7.5, 1.5,           
5.4, 7.7, 0, 9.5, 9.9, 3.4, 3.9, 8.9, 0, 2.6, 8.2, 4.7), Beijing = c(6.2,           
1.8, 4.4, 6.7, 2.3, 6.5, 2.8, 2.1, 5.1, 8.3, 9.2, 2.3, 4, 4.1,          
0.2), Paris = c(9.9, 9.2, 7.2, 9.1, 9.8, 5.4, 5.7, 6.3, 5.8,            
5.8, 9.7, 4.6, 7.2, 5, 4), Hong.Kong = c(4.1, 4.8, 4.5, 2.9,            
0.2, 0.2, 2.8, 9.3, 0.7, 7.3, 2.8, 5.9, 5.5, 8.9, 1), Wellington = c(3.4,           
9.9, 6.6, 9, 3.1, 0.5, 2.5, 8.4, 1.8, 4.7, 0.2, 2.8, 1, 3, 7.8          
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.expanded <- df[rep(row.names(df), ifelse(df$Mumbai==0.0,2,1)),]

df.expanded
     Shanghai Mumbai Beijing Paris Hong.Kong Wellington
1         5.7    0.4     6.2   9.9       4.1        3.4
2         5.1    7.5     1.8   9.2       4.8        9.9
3         5.0    1.5     4.4   7.2       4.5        6.6
4         5.7    5.4     6.7   9.1       2.9        9.0
5         8.2    7.7     2.3   9.8       0.2        3.1
6         3.4    0.0     6.5   5.4       0.2        0.5
6.1       3.4    0.0     6.5   5.4       0.2        0.5
7         1.0    9.5     2.8   5.7       2.8        2.5
8         8.4    9.9     2.1   6.3       9.3        8.4
9         3.8    3.4     5.1   5.8       0.7        1.8
10        4.5    3.9     8.3   5.8       7.3        4.7
11        5.3    8.9     9.2   9.7       2.8        0.2
12        0.7    0.0     2.3   4.6       5.9        2.8
12.1      0.7    0.0     2.3   4.6       5.9        2.8
13        1.4    2.6     4.0   7.2       5.5        1.0
14        4.7    8.2     4.1   5.0       8.9        3.0
15        8.9    4.7     0.2   4.0       1.0        7.8
```

Why this works:
This subset call requests the list of row names, where each row name (i.e., number) is repeated once if Mumbai does not equal 0, and twice if it does. As a result, you get a table with the Mumbai==0 lines duplicated (and their row number with an added .1).

Answer (score 1):

We could use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` to add rows to `df` where `Mumbai == 0`.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df, df %>%
     filter(Mumbai == 0))
```

---

Or using `rbind` from base R

```
rbind(df, df[df$Mumbai == 0,])
```

---

If we want to add the duplicate lines just below then we can do

```
df[sort(c(1:nrow(df) , which(df$Mumbai == 0))), ]

#     Shanghai Mumbai Beijing Paris Hong.Kong Wellington
#1         5.7    0.4     6.2   9.9       4.1        3.4
#2         5.1    7.5     1.8   9.2       4.8        9.9
#3         5.0    1.5     4.4   7.2       4.5        6.6
#4         5.7    5.4     6.7   9.1       2.9        9.0
#5         8.2    7.7     2.3   9.8       0.2        3.1
#6         3.4    0.0     6.5   5.4       0.2        0.5
#6.1       3.4    0.0     6.5   5.4       0.2        0.5
#7         1.0    9.5     2.8   5.7       2.8        2.5
#8         8.4    9.9     2.1   6.3       9.3        8.4
#9         3.8    3.4     5.1   5.8       0.7        1.8
#10        4.5    3.9     8.3   5.8       7.3        4.7
#11        5.3    8.9     9.2   9.7       2.8        0.2
#12        0.7    0.0     2.3   4.6       5.9        2.8
#12.1      0.7    0.0     2.3   4.6       5.9        2.8
#13        1.4    2.6     4.0   7.2       5.5        1.0
#14        4.7    8.2     4.1   5.0       8.9        3.0
#15        8.9    4.7     0.2   4.0       1.0        7.8
```

Comment: But this solution doesn't add the duplicate lines directly under the ones with `Mumbai==0` as requested by OP.

Comment: @iod I thought OP wants to use the dataframe for further manipulation so order won't matter. Maybe you are correct, I have added another method which maintains the order. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[sort(c(seq_len(.N),.I[!Mumbai]))]]
#    Shanghai Mumbai Beijing Paris Hong.Kong Wellington
# 1:      5.7    0.4     6.2   9.9       4.1        3.4
# 2:      5.1    7.5     1.8   9.2       4.8        9.9
# 3:      5.0    1.5     4.4   7.2       4.5        6.6
# 4:      5.7    5.4     6.7   9.1       2.9        9.0
# 5:      8.2    7.7     2.3   9.8       0.2        3.1
# 6:      3.4    0.0     6.5   5.4       0.2        0.5
# 7:      3.4    0.0     6.5   5.4       0.2        0.5
# 8:      1.0    9.5     2.8   5.7       2.8        2.5
# 9:      8.4    9.9     2.1   6.3       9.3        8.4
#10:      3.8    3.4     5.1   5.8       0.7        1.8
#11:      4.5    3.9     8.3   5.8       7.3        4.7
#12:      5.3    8.9     9.2   9.7       2.8        0.2
#13:      0.7    0.0     2.3   4.6       5.9        2.8
#14:      0.7    0.0     2.3   4.6       5.9        2.8
#15:      1.4    2.6     4.0   7.2       5.5        1.0
#16:      4.7    8.2     4.1   5.0       8.9        3.0
#17:      8.9    4.7     0.2   4.0       1.0        7.8
```

Or

```
setDT(df)[df[, sort(c(seq_len(.N),.I[!Mumbai]))]]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(n = (!Mumbai) + 1) %>%
   uncount(n)
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df[sort(c(seq_len(nrow(df)), which(!df$Mumbai))),]
```